# What is the "security context" referenced in Role.getRoles(context, callback)

Tags: loopback

In loopback `Role.getRoles(context, callback)` they refer to the context in the docs as "The security context" in this [link](http://apidocs.loopback.io/loopback/#role-getroles).

What is the security context and how to pass it to get user roles for example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Аs stated in the documentation, LoopBack’s access control system is built around a few core concepts. Among them "Principal" - an entity that can be identified or authenticated. There are three base "principalType" - APP(LICATION), USER, ROLE. Each specific principal object have an "principalId" - ID of the principal - such as appId, userId or roleId.

The getRoles function takes as a parameter **context** as instanceof AccessContext or cast to it (http://apidocs.loopback.io/loopback/#accesscontext) and list roles for a given **principal**.

The AccessContext function (for cast) also accepts a single principal defined with the following properties:

```
{ principalType: 'USER', principalId: '2' }
```

In the same way we can define context when requesting roles:

```
Role.getRoles({ principalType: 'USER', principalId: '2' }, (err, roles) => {
            if (err) console.log(err);
            console.log(roles);
          });
```

And get an array of role **IDs** (including dynamic) for user with id "2".